# Why is LLDB's print (or p) command so limited?

Tags: c++, lldb

When I first heard about it, it sounded like a great feature—a c++ REPL. However, it cannot call STL functions or methods, and has a whole lot of other issues. This question also applies to conditional breakpoints.

Is it still an experimental feature, or have the developers just dropped it?

Example:

```
(lldb) p iterator->aField
error: call to a function 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<aClass const*>::operator->() const' ('_ZNKSt3__111__wrap_iterIPK8aClassEptEv') that is not present in the target
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

Comment: isn't it rather that the `operator->` function has been inlined by the compiler?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: if the function is inlined and not present in the executable, the debugger has hardly any chance to call it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be able to interpret (at least) code from the template on the fly? (At least eventually; if this is an experimental feature, they might not have had time to do that yet)

Comment: "Shouldn't it be able to interpret (at least) code from the template on the fly?" – um… nope.

Comment: That would require the debugger knowing the actual internal structure of the class [not just what the fields are called and what type they are, but also "how they interact and how to get the data out from that", which isn't entirely trivial in many cases]

Comment: Mats & TPC are correct, lldb would have to somehow recompile all that was necessary of STL to build a correct specialization of this inlined template, which means knowing all the STL build logic, etc.  Not something lldb is really set up to do.  There is a Clang initiative to make "Modules" for C++ analogous to the Module support added for C & ObjC in the past year or so.  When that piece of work is done, then we can ingest the modules and that should allow us to rebuild STL template class methods.

Comment: It doesn't require superhuman effort to have a database of smart pointer types, with hardcoded rules how to resolve `->`. For e.g. `std::unique_ptr` that rule would probably just be `use _Ptr member at offset 0`. IIRC, that's roughly how MSVC++ handles it.

Comment: LLDB does this too.  See http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html if you want more details. It is easy to use that sort of information for presenting variables and the results of expressions.  But inserting that information into clang mid-compile so that it can generate proper code for arbitrarily complex expressions is a much harder trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, there's no good way for the debugger to generate methods of template specializations for which the compiler only emitted inlined versions.  And the debugger can't call inlined methods.

Here's one limited trick (though it requires C++11) that you can use to force the compiler to generate full copies of the relevant template class so that there are functions the debugger can call.  For instance, if I put:

```
template class std::vector<int>;
```

in my source code somewhere, the compiler will generate real copies of all the functions in the int specialization of std::vector.  This obviously isn't a full solution, and you should only do this in debug builds or it will bloat your code.  But when there are a couple of types that you really call methods on, its a useful trick to know.

You mention a "whole lot of other issues".  Please file bugs on any expression parser issues you find in lldb, either with the lldb bugzilla: https://llvm.org/bugs, or Apple's bug reporter: http://bugreporter.apple.com.  The expression parser is under active development